# i try to solve this issue but i get the following Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image: error]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
**TypeScript-ReactJs

as you see i get the following Error :

The element is implicitly of type "any" because the expression of type "any" cannot be used for the index type "NotificationApi".

```
import { Button, notification, Row, Col, Card } from "antd";

import React, { FC } from "react";

export const NotificationExample: FC<any> = () => {
    const openNotificationWithIcon = (type: any): void => {
        notification[type]({
            duration: 0,
            message: "Notification Title",
            description:
                "This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification.",
        });
    };

    return (
        <Card
            type="inner"
            title="Notification"
            bodyStyle={{ padding: "32px 32px 16px 32px" }}
            extra={
                <Button icon="external-link-alt" href="https://ant.design/components/notification/" target="_blank">
                    AntDesign
                </Button>
            }
        >
            <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
                <Col span={24}>
                    <div className="divider">Types</div>
                    <Button onClick={() => openNotificationWithIcon("open")} className="margin-right-md">
                        Default
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => openNotificationWithIcon("success")} className="margin-right-md">
                        Success
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => openNotificationWithIcon("info")} className="margin-right-md">
                        Info
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => openNotificationWithIcon("warning")} className="margin-right-md">
                        Warning
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => openNotificationWithIcon("error")}>Error</Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

Comment: Please write meaningful titles that summarize the issue that you are facing. [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update type from `any` to keys of `notification`

```
const openNotificationWithIcon = (
    type: "open" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | "error"
  ): void
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
const openNotificationWithIcon = (type: string): void => {
    const content = {
      duration: 0,
      message: "Notification Title",
      description:
        "This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification."
    };
    switch (type) {
      case "open":
        notification.open(content);
        break;
      case "success":
        notification.success(content);
        break;
      case "info":
        notification.info(content);
        break;
      case "warning":
        notification.warning(content);
        break;
      case "error":
        notification.error(content);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

Comment: @Danoosh Jooybar , thanks a lot it work like charm :D

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason for you getting that error is because

1. You have a TypeScript configuration which doesn't allow for implicit 'any'.
2. You're trying to access a property with type 'any', but 'any' isn't allowed as an index type when implicit 'any' is forbidden.

The first part is a good thing and you probably want to keep it that way.

The latter is because the notification object doesn't have just "any" property. It has specific properties, for example the "open", "success", "info", "warning" and "error" that you're using. Trying to use 'any' as an index type would give you a result of type 'any'.

To avoid the issue, you can simply type the 'type' parameter for example as

```
"open" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | "error"
```

Answer (score -1):

why did you defined `type` as `any`, while it's a `string`?
I think you may solve your problem by changing `any` to `string`.